# Android- How to send invitations to friends using Firebase in-app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app using Firebase that let's people send event invitation to their friends on the app. They will be given the option to choose from a list of their friends on the database, and those selected will be sent the event invitation. Each event is given it's own key/unique Id, and I need it to be saved under their selected friends' userUID. So, how would I be able to save the event id to multiple friends that the user selected?

I know how to save the event to the user's own database like this:

```
newEvent.child(userUID).setValue(eventID);
```

But I am having trouble saving it to other peoples'. Thanks

Comment: Check if this solve your problem,            Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder("Invite title")
                        .setEmailSubject("")
                        .setEmailHtmlContent("")
                        .setMessage("")
                        .setDeepLink(Uri.parse(""))
                   .setCustomImage(Uri.parse(""))
                        .setCallToActionText("Open")
                        .build();
                startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.RequestCode.INVITE);

Comment: No no, the invitation isn't sent through mail, it is sent in-app

Comment: `newEvent.child(userUID).child(friendUID).setValue(eventID);`

Comment: Can friendUID be set to multiple values? I.e. more than one friend? @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do client-side fan out: writing the same value to multiple places. It is possible to do this with a single multi-location update:

```
usersRef = ref.child("users");
Map updates = new HashMap();
updates.put(userUID+"/"+friendUID1, eventID);
updates.put(userUID+"/"+friendUID2, eventID);
usersRef.updateChildren(updates);
```

Just make sure that you have the path to the individual properties you want to update in the keys of the hashmap.

Comment: Does this mean the number of friends the user want to invite is static?

Comment: No. You can also loop through a collection of friends to populate the map.